# I am not able to resume my audio where i Paused

Tags: android, media-player

*i have multiple audio in recycleview and when i pause a audio after that i am not able to resume where i paused ..always audio start from starting..and also when i click to play or pause then other media player also perform seek bar*

**This is click of play pause**

```
((HolderAudio) holder).iv_play_audio_dash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                            ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).pb_audio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                                ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).iv_play_audio_dash.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play_audio));
                                ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio)holder).gif_soundwave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mediaPlayer.pause();
                              //  mediaPlayer.reset();

                                pausePosition=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                                Log.e("cureeenntt",pausePosition+"");
                                ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).pb_audio.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }else {
                                Log.e("thisss","1");

                                prepareSong(list.get(position).getAudio(),((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder),position);
                            }
                    }
                });
```

**this prepare song mathod**

```
        private void prepareSong(String audio, final HolderAudio holder, final int position) {

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }

            try {
               mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audio);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if (mp.isPlaying()){
                            mp.pause();
                            Log.e("thisss","2");

                            holder.pb_audio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.iv_play_audio_dash.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause_btn));
                        }

                        playSong(mp,holder,lastPosition,position);


                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }







    }
```

**this is play song mathod**

```
    private void playSong(final MediaPlayer mp, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int lastPosition, final int position) {


    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.pause();
        Log.e("thisss","3");

    } else {

        Log.e("thisss","4");
        mp.start();

        ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).pb_audio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).iv_play_audio_dash.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause_btn));
        ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).gif_soundwave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (lastPosition==position){
                    ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).iv_play_audio_dash.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause_btn));
                    ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).gif_soundwave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).iv_play_audio_dash.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play_audio));
                    ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).gif_soundwave.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

                int currentPosition;
                int currentpos;
                ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).seekBar.setMax((int) mp.getDuration() / 1000);
                currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;

                /*if (pausePosition > 1) {
                    currentPosition = pausePosition / 1000;
                    currentpos=pausePosition;
                    mp.start();

                    Log.e("thisss","5");

                } else {

                    currentpos=mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    Log.e("thisss","6");
                    mp.start();
                }*/


                if (mp.isPlaying()){
                    ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).iv_play_audio_dash.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause_btn));
                }else {
                    ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).iv_play_audio_dash.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play_audio));

                }
                ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);


                ((AdapterDashBoard.HolderAudio) holder).tv_audioTimer.setText(Utility.convertDuration((long) mp.
                        getCurrentPosition()));
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that the same MediaPlayer object is used each time and re-initialized on prepareSong. You can maintain the pause time of song and start from stored time.

Comment: i did pause play..but now the thing is when i  click pause and play then other media players seekbar also change @Jay